# Is there a standard way to write Cos instead Math.Cos without defining your own Cos function?

Tags: c#

I just started looking at C# and verbose Math functions bother me. Is there a standard way to write `Cos` (or any other Math function) instead `Math.Cos` without defining your own Cos function?

Comment: so you don't want to write a new function, you don't want to use built-in method. **what do you want ?**

Comment: Can you give us an example of the way that you want to call the Cosine function?

Comment: Writing `Math.Cos` *is* the standard way in C#...

Comment: @Selman22 @Pete I want to write `Cos` similarly to the way most other programming languages and mathematicians do. I don't want to write `Math.Cos`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to the new [Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.com) compiler, then write

```
using System.Math;
```

Comment: Does it mean that C# 6.0 introduces a change and allows both `Math.Cos(x)` and `Cos(x)`?

Comment: @Paul  C# 6.0 extends `using` and allows to import all public static methods of a type into the current namespace.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answer, within the context of the standard compiler, is No.  C# has no support for modules, nor for global methods.  Everything has to belong to a class.  `Math` is a class, `Cos()` is a static method belonging to that class.  To call it, you have to reference the class.  The **only** methods you can call directly are those that belong to the class in which you are calling them.

The best you could probably do is to make up a bunch of delegates, but that feels a bit... silly.

```
class Program
{
    delegate double MyCos(double x);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyCos cos = new MyCos(Math.Cos);
        Console.WriteLine(cos(Math.PI));           
    }
}
```

Otherwise, there's always VB :

```
Imports System.Math
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(Cos(PI))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

But Roslyn looks SO interesting.. It is just a preview atm; better wait a few more hours/days..